# Error installing RVM

Tags: rvm

I am following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-using-rvm), but this is the output I receive. What am the problem?

```
dbugger@mercury:~$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
--rails Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /home/dbugger/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /home/dbugger/.profile /home/dbugger/.bashrc /home/dbugger/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /home/dbugger/.bash_profile /home/dbugger/.zlogin. Upgrade of RVM in /home/dbugger/.rvm/ is complete.

# Enrique,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.


rvm 1.25.27 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time. No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.1.2. Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies. Checking requirements for ubuntu. Installing requirements for ubuntu. Updating system.......... Installing required packages: gawk, libreadline6-dev, libssl-dev, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev, sqlite3.... Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install gawk libreadline6-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3', showing last 15 lines of /home/dbugger/.rvm/log/1401804140_ruby-2.1.2/package_install_gawk_libreadline6-dev_libssl-dev_libyaml-dev_libsqlite3-dev_sqlite3.log
++ /scripts/functions/utility : __rvm_try_sudo()  405 > sudo -p '%p password required for '\''apt-get --no-install-recommends --yes install gawk libreadline6-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3'\'': ' apt-get --no-install-recommends --yes install gawk libreadline6-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state information... Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
++ /scripts/functions/utility : __rvm_try_sudo()  405 > return 100
++ /scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu : requirements_debian_libs_install()  36 > return 100 Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by enabling the "updates" repository

Answer (score 0):

The most conveniently solution should be:

1. Select the main Ubuntu apt repository source. Ubuntu org should fix the dependency problem quickly. If you are using a mirror repository, there will be a delay because mirror need to sync with the main server.
2. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Now, you are able to install what you need.